# Windows 8 Blocks the installation of Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, windows-8, frameworks

I want to install .NET Framework 4.0 on My windows 8, but T got this message

"Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 is already a part of this operating system......"

I follow the steps to resolve the problem described into this page
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765375

but the problem is persist and I cannot install .net

Comment: It is already installed, the 4.5 flavor.  You cannot remove it, that would break existing programs that depend on 4.5 being installed.  Best to stop trying to break your operating system.  If testing with 4.0 is absolutely necessary then using a VM that boots, say, Win7 would be to proper approach.

Comment: I did not attempt to remove any framework at all!.

Comment: you cannot install because it is already there.Can you mention why are you trying this, what is your actual problem that made you do this.